# Liquid Fill Gauge outer circle arc with space count

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to create an outer circle arc with space in d3 js in Liquid Fill Gauge?

http://plnkr.co/edit/meDtUEuElEccVHuZYGwv?p=preview

I want to change outer circle arc with space in above fig.

Like that: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/04hDF0c9UXOm02tvUW9v?p=preview
show in fig

```
var data = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5];
var svg = d3.select('body')
       .append('svg')
       .attr('width', 600)
       .attr('height', 200);
var group = svg.append('g')
               .attr('transform', 'translate(300, 100)');
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(44)
            .outerRadius(59);
var pie = d3.layout.pie().padAngle(.02).value(function(d){return d;});
var arcs = group.selectAll('.arc')
                .data(pie(data))
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'arc');
arcs.append('path').attr('d', arc).attr('fill', '#92d14f');
```